# How do I return all records from two tables using a like condition in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm a developer trying to do some SQL Server 2008 and I am stuck.

I have the following two tables

Table 1

```
Local Area   | ManagerID  
 ABC-SDF-LKJ | 1234  
 ABC-KJH-GHJ | 4321  
 XZY-TRS-YEU | 4321  
 XZY-BFG-GFH | 6789  
 INT-HSL-DSL | 6789
```

Table 2

```
Region | ManagerID  
 ABC   | 4321  
 INT   | 5764  
 XZY   | 8647
```

I need to create a query that will return all rows for a `ManagerId`. If a `ManagerId` exists in table 2 then it should return all rows from table 1 they are the manager for and all rows from table 1 that start with the region they are manager for.

Given the data above `ManagerId = 4321` should return

```
ABC-SDF-LKJ  
ABC-KJH-GHJ  
XZY-TRS-YEU
```

While `ManagerId = 8647` should return

```
XZY-BFG-GFH  
XZY-TRS-YEU
```

and `ManagerId = 1234` should return

```
ABC-SDF-LKJ
```

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: The contents of the 'Local Area' column should really be split into three columns. You're hurting yourself here. And my eyes.

Comment: @flup I agree, I have inherited the DB and changes are a no no :(

Comment: Nothing creative you can do? Computed columns? View? Extra table filled with a trigger?

Comment: @flup We have two DBAs that keep a very close eye on all changes

Comment: Ask them to think with you on how to solve this, cause they'll surely agree it's bad design.

Comment: @flup I'm sure they would, however the system is highly visible, huge and used by many other systems. The fear of breaking something out weighs the need/desire for elegant design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `JOIN` can be on an arbitrary expression, and rather than a `LIKE`, I would use `LEFT([Local Area], 3)`.  The `LEFT JOIN` will return those regions listed in `Table2`, while. the condition for `t1.ManagerId = xxxx` will return values in `Table1` which have no match in `Table2`, like those for `ManagerID = 1234`.

```
SELECT
  [Local Area]
FROM
  Table1 t1
  -- Matches the Region back to the Local Area
  LEFT JOIN Table2 T2 ON LEFT(t1.[Local Area], 3) = t2.Region
WHERE
  -- For those which have no Region match in Table2
  t1.ManagerId = 1234
  -- And to get the Table1 records which start with the Region from Table2
  OR t2.ManagerId = 1234
```

Here's a demonstration: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ca497/4

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1 T1, Table2 T2
WHERE T1.ManagerID = T2.ManagerID 
OR T1.[Local Area] LIKE T2.Region + '%'
```

The first condition takes care of the same manager, the second condition takes care of the region / area.

Sql fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a0e0b/4).

Comment: good answer +1, but not quite what I was after. I'm sure it will help others. Thanks for the answer.